# How does one sensibly allocate memory during deserialization?

Tags: c++, memory, serialization, deserialization

I am currently attempting to create a serialization system in c++. The initial act of serialization is pretty straightforward, as is most of deserialization. I have hit a big of a snag when it comes to creating objects that don't exist yet when deserializing a tree of objects. This is, of course, a non-issue for objects that are automatically/stack allocated. If the object has no expectations on the memory itself this is also pretty simple using just operator new.

The problem I'm having is, what if there are explicit expectations of the memory the object belongs to?  Such as, what if the object belongs to a memory pool? I need to both somehow communicate that to the serialization system and put in logic for handling it.

I've thought of using registration to do these things, but that is a very, very easy thing to over-engineer and I want to avoid that. Is there a common solution to this that I've missed? If not and the problem/decision space is known, what is it? If even that isn't known, any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Resources on the overlap between memory allocation and deserialization seem to be a bit scarce.

Comment: C libraries often provide a way to pass in custom alloc and free functions. The C++ way might be to pass in an allocator object like the standard containters.

Comment: I'd expect deserialization to return things instantiated with `new`, or depending on the containers available, some other type of structure that can be passed around cheaply. For example, if deserializing a tree, it'd return a pointer to an allocated root node.

Comment: This is actually a hard problem to solve. A universal approach of allocators can be problematic. See, for example, removal of allocator support of `std::function`. For the limited case you might be successful, but generalization beyond that could be elusive.

Comment: Where possible I'd return the tree by value and let copy elision do its job. After that it's the responsibility of the tree's destructor to handle clean-up when I'm done with it.

Comment: Creating a general-purpose de-/serializer, that would work with many structures is nearly impossible. Because no one says that one type is allocated the same way throughout the structure. There can be combinations of `new`, placement `new`, pooling, with different pools, … . When writing a de-/serializer, you usually limit the scenarios. You could allow the user to define functions for de-/serialization for a certain type (like [nlohmann/json: Arbitrary types conversions](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#arbitrary-types-conversions) does), but that's still limited.

Comment: @MukeshIngham Allocators were the solution I was considering prior to posting. Use template specialization to detect the custom allocators and fill those with the logic necessary. It still feels a bit heavy handed, but if that's what I got then that's what I got.